# Bash script to run command in localized CLI

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a command that access a local switch CLI and runs a simple 'show config'. The script logs in, but then does nothing. I suspect it's because once logged in to the sub-terminal, the commands can't be interpreted. Any ideas?

```
$a1 = "show config"

exec cli

sleep 2

exec $a1
exec exit
```

Comment: Could you clarify "that access a local switch CLI"? is it about a network switch? Do you use ssh somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

After `exec cli`, your shell script does not return to run the next line, `sleep 2` 
To be exact, it no longer exists, because `exec` replaces the shell process by the new `cli` process.

I suspect you do not really want the effect of `exec`, and should remove it.

I am not really sure what you want to do, but assuming you want to run the command `show config` in `cli`, try just writing the command to it's input:

```
printf "show config" | cli
```

For similar, but really difficult cases, see `expect`